# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'

Tags: asp-classic, runtime-error

I recently inherited a website in ASP, which I am not familiar with. Yesterday, one of the pages began to throw an error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'

Subscript out of range: 'i'

default.asp, line 19
```

Here is the code from lines 13-27:

```
<%
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open "SELECT * FROM VENDORS_LIST_TBL WHERE inStr('"& dVendorStr &"','|'&ID&'|')", Cn

DIM dTitle(100), dDescription(100), dLink(100)
i = 0 : Do while NOT rs.EOF : i = i + 1
dTitle(i) = rs.fields.item("dTitle").value
dDescription(i) = rs.fields.item("dDescription").value
dLink(i) = rs.fields.item("dLink").value : if dLink(i) <> "" then dTitle(i) = "<a href=""" & dLink(i) & """>" & dTitle(i) & "</a>"
if NOT rs.EOF then rs.movenext
Loop
x = i

rs.Close : Set rs = Nothing
%>
```

Any ideas on what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You might consider the ADO Recordset's `GetRows` method which returns atwo dimensional array.

Comment: In light of the other two answers it is necessary to provide you with a "this is how this should be done" sort of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared dTitle, dDescription and dLink as Arrays with a size of 100.  As you are walking through the recordset, you are assigning elements to those arrays.  It would appear that you have more than 100 records in your recordset, so the logic is trying to do something like:

```
dTitle(101) = rs.fields.item("dTitle").value
```

This will throw an error because your array isn't big enough to hold all of your data.

Comment: re: *I increased the limit to 500.*  That's a bad idea. You need to not set the limit to a static number.  like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072016/48082

Answer (score 2):

The "solution" you chose is not very good. What if within 2 years there will be more than 500? You will forget all about this and waste hours yet again.

Instead of fixed size arrays you can just use dynamic arrays:

```
DIM dTitle(), dDescription(), dLink()
ReDim dTitle(0)
ReDim dDescription(0)
ReDim dLink(0)
i = 0
Do while NOT rs.EOF
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve dTitle(i)
    ReDim Preserve dDescription(i)
    ReDim Preserve dLink(i)    
    dTitle(i) = rs.fields.item("dTitle").value
    dDescription(i) = rs.fields.item("dDescription").value
    dLink(i) = rs.fields.item("dLink").value
    If (Not(IsNull(dLink(i)))) And (dLink(i) <> "") Then
        dTitle(i) = "<a href=""" & dLink(i) & """>" & dTitle(i) & "</a>"
    End If
    rs.movenext
Loop
```

This will start with one (empty) item in each array - for some reason the code seems to need this - then on each iteration one more item will be added, preserving the others.

Note that I've also fixed small issue that might have caused trouble - in case of NULL value in "dLink" field, you would get blank anchors in your HTML because NULL is not empty string in VBScript.

Comment: Do not use this approach.  Each iternation of the while loop (ie for each record) each array needs to allocate a new block of memory, copy all of its current elements to the new block and deallocate the previous array memory.  This might be fine for a few records but would exponentially degrade in preformance with larger number of records.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones you consider ~100 records large number? With modern CPU and memory I don't think it's an issue. However it's still pretty simple to allocate 50 items each time - still better than having fixed size array that might fail.

Comment: Answers in Stackoverflow are not just there for the sole benefit of the questioner.  It may be that for just a hundred records this might not be too bad but in general it is poor practice.  Of course what is unspecified by the Question is how many concurrent ASP requests may be running this code at the same time.  20 concurrent active requests would effectively turn those 300 reallocations of an array into 6000.  This also represents a rapid fragmentation of the memory space, on 64 bit perhaps not a problem but I've seen it do bad things to 32 bit servers in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This how `GetRows` can be used to achieve the same goal.

```
<% 

Function VendorSearch(sVendor)

    Dim cn:  Set cn = SomeLibraryFunctionThatOpensAConnection()
    Dim cmd: Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dTitle, dDescription, dLink FROM VENDORS_LIST_TBL WHERE inStr(?,'|'&ID&'|')"
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("Vendor", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(sVendor), sVendor)
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    Dim rs : Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    VendorSearch = rs.GetRows()

    rs.Close()
    cn.Close()
End Function

Dim arrVendor : arrVendor =  VendorSearch(dVendorStr)

Const cTitle = 0, cDesc = 1, cLink = 2

Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(arrVendor, 2)
    If IsNull(arrVendor(cLink, i) Or arrVendor(cLink, i) = "" Then
        arrVendor(cTitle, i) = "<a href=""" & arrVendor(cLink, i) & """>" & arr(cTitle, i) & "</a>"
    End If 
Next

%>
```

Notes:

- The Select statement contains only those fields required in the results, the use of * should be avoided
- A parameterised command is used to avoid SQL Injection threat from SQL contactenation.
- Constants used for field indices into the resulting 2 dimensional array.
- Whilst this code replicates the original munging of the title value this is here as an example only.  In reality construction of HTML should be left as late as possible and outputing of all such strings as title and description should be passed through `Server.HTMLEncode` before sending to the response.